# Hide layers by default on CartoDB visualization

Tags: carto, carto-js

I'm loading a CartoDB visualization and I want all layers to be switched off as the default setting, so users have to switch them on using the layer selector loaded with the visualization.

I'm reallly new on leaflet and cartodbjs so not sure where to begin to dive in the code. I think is related with [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/108656/how-to-add-multiple-cartodb-layers-in-viz-json-to-a-leaflet-layer-control) but it doesn't have any answer.

I have a sample code on [gist](https://gist.github.com/jsanz/92c80ebd155f8b2e02f5) ([demo](http://bl.ocks.org/jsanz/92c80ebd155f8b2e02f5)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find attached [some example code](http://bl.ocks.org/matallo/6f1aa6e9e7d70d77068c). You can access the layers/sublayers through the [javascript API](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/cartodb-js.html#cartodbvis) *layer[0]* is the basemap and *layer[1](http://bl.ocks.org/matallo/6f1aa6e9e7d70d77068c)* is the main layer with your two sublayers.

Anyway I recommend you creating this visualization with [CreateLayer](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/cartodb-js.html#adding-cartodb-layers-to-an-existing-map) as when hiding the sublayers the toggle layers controls won't update.

Cheers

Comment: Hi @matallo, you code works but the layer selector is not updated with the change of the status of the layer. I thought that the code should interact with it but I haven't found a method on the overlay to do that.

Comment: Ohh, you mentioned it, sorry :-)

I'll use CreateLayer as you say to have more control over the process.

Answer (score 0):

Wladimir find a better solution interacting with the overlays

http://bl.ocks.org/bolollo/28f1447492232da0b7af

```
          //get the data layers
          var overlays = layers[1].getSubLayers();
          overlays.forEach(function(overlay) {
            overlay.hide();
          });

          //get the layer selector control
          var control = vis.getOverlay("layer_selector");
          //redraw layer selector to update the states
          control.render();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see a code that hides the layers when the map starts and updates the control layer selection.
https://gist.github.com/bolollo/28f1447492232da0b7af